# Can i reuse staging buffer for multiple vertex buffer in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

My application has multiple vertex buffers that contain dynamic data which is updated every frame. I'm not sure whether I can use the same staging buffer to update all the vertex buffers, or if I must create a staging buffer for each vertex buffer. If I do need to create a staging buffer for each vertex buffer, what is the difference compared to just creating host-visible vertex buffer and update them with memory mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "creating a staging buffer". If you're talking about whether you can use the same `VkBuffer` object for staging to multiple destination regions of memory, yes. So long as you follow the alignment requirements of the memory transfer, you can use a single buffer object to transfer to however many destination buffers (or images) you like.

However, if you're talking about reusing the same *region of memory* for multiple staging operations, that's a bad idea if you're trying to do it in the same frame. Remember: the whole point of staging is to not stall the CPU by making it wait on a GPU operation when transferring data. If you write to some region of memory, transfer from it to device-local memory, and then want to write to it again, the CPU must wait until the transfer is complete.

Using different regions from the same buffer object is fine. Using the same region from the same buffer object in the same frame is not fine. Next frame is OK because the transfer will probably be complete by then, so you won't wait for any real length of time.

> what is the difference compared to just creating host-visible vertex buffer and update them with memory mapping?

Your implementation does not have to allow its users to use vertex buffers attached to host-visible memory. Most often will, but it's something you have to check for. And for streaming vertex data (particularly in bulk), this would be preferable to staging if the host-visible memory is also device-local.

Or to put it another way, staging for buffer data should be thought of as what you have to do if you can't use host-visible/device-local mapped memory. Or if your access patterns for that memory are not good ones for CPU writing (sequential accesses are good, everything else is less good).

And FYI: only unmap a piece of memory if you're about to deallocate it. There is no reason not to keep mapable memory permanently mapped.

Comment: Do i need to create staging buffer if the device-local memory is already host-visible, it seems redundant

Comment: @zhuah: The term "staging buffer" typically refers to a place you write data to that then gets copied to its eventual destination. If the only memory available is both device-local and host-visible, you don't need to copy buffer data anywhere (but you don't want to overwrite data already in use, so you will need multiple buffering). But you still have to stage images because it's not possible to directly write image data in a format the GPU can read it.